# How to pass value to jmeter variable using robotframework

Tags: jmeter, robotframework, jmeter-plugins

i have created  a variable ${url} in jmeter and i want to pass the value for the same using robot framework .

Below is the robot script where i am passing the value of url using ${url} but it is not working.I tried all the solution mentioned in stackworkflow but nothing is working for me.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    JMeterLib


*** Variables ***
${url}     demoqa.com
*** Test Cases ***
Get_weather_info

    Run Jmeter   /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/HTTP Request.jmx  /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/logs/log.jtl  -Jurl=${url}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are passing the value of `url` **property** but I fail to see where you're reading them.

Replace this `${url}` with `${__P(url,)}` and your configuration should start working as expected.

More information:

- [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
- [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)